# Sending msg and post on own wall function no longer work

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created social feeds functions(sending msg to friends and posting on own wall) using javascript SDK and graph API in Facebook 2-3 months ago for my apps. It was working perfectly when I created but now, when I visit my app and try to use them again, it no longer works. It's so strange since I never touched that code after I implemented them. I even tried to copy and pasting exact sample javascript code given in Facebook document and it didn't work either. Even after I re-write my code, it still doesn't work either. I have no idea what is wrong. Anyone face similar problem with javascript SDK? Thanks in advance.

Hi,

The code is here: Sorry for late reply.

```
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
      <script> 
      FB.init({
         appId  : 'id',
         status : true, // check login status
         cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
       });
      </script>
      <script>



        function share_wall() {
          // calling the API ...
          var obj = {
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/id/',

            name: 'test',
            description: 'blalala'
          };
          FB.ui(obj);
        }   
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code here?

Comment: And when you say 'no longer works', any chance you could elaborate on what that means?

Comment: Do a callback and see if you are getting any response back. Besides this, is there any other JavaScript SDK function that is not working as well?

Comment: 'No longer works' means it doesn't post anything or display anything when I click hyperlink which supposed to invoke javascript feed and send. I was trying to check with firebug but I still cannot find what it wrong. All facebook javascript SDK functions are not working. Other normal javascript are ok. @zany, how do I do a callback?

Comment: When I take out function and just run the code, it works. but if I want to call the function, it cannot work. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You can follow the callback function in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ . Also, check if your `FB` and the value in `appId` are valid in this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I actually have the same problem as you =\ Go to your app settings and make the additional configuration under Basic Settings.

If your domain is http://inspiration.nyp.edu.sg

[image]

If you are working on localhost

[image]

**"Symptoms"**

- Previously, your JavaScript SDK functions were working fine. Now, executing your JavaScript SDK functions prompts you either an API Error Code 191 or an error.
  [image]
  [image]
- Your PHP SDK functions are working fine.
- Your JavaScript SDK functions work fine when you run your application as App on Facebook, but does not when you run your application as a Page Tab.

(For my case, the last date I checked was 7 August 2012 and my JavaScript SDK functions were working fine. It was until 3 September 2012 when I checked them again, then I encountered the errors mentioned above.)

**I highly recommend everyone to check their Page Tab application's JavaScript SDK functions such as `feed` dialog, `apprequests` and etc.**

Comment: Hi, my feed dialog don't even work on apps and I tried to solve it by what you have done here but it did work either. I have no error but just feed dialog and sending message function not working. Any idea? Thank.

Comment: @ATZ Are the codes still the same as posted above? Do you have any other functions that are not working as well?

Comment: Hi, yes. It is still the same as posted above. Nothing changes. I tried the same function with PHP and it worked but there is no pop up window like javascript SDK.