# API Error Code: 191 occurs only in Page Tab application

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I've this error only when the app is in the page tab:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

In page tab http://www.facebook.com/pages/ConMar/268459383261877?sk=app_148000545338378 if you click on "Invita Amici" you see the error.

But with the App in facebbok I don't have the problem, it works fine: http://apps.facebook.com/family-and-friends/

Both "URL canvas:" and "Page Tab URL:" ar set to: "http://www.d4v1d3.com/family-friends/"

I use the example code:

FB.init({
         appId   : 'xxxxxxxxxx',
         frictionlessRequests: true
      });

```
  function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request'
    }, requestCallback);
  }
```

Do you know why I' ve the error just in the case of page tab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app settings and make the additional configuration under Basic Settings.

If your domain is http://inspiration.nyp.edu.sg

[image]

If you are working on localhost

[image]

You can refer to [Sending msg and post on own wall function no longer work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027511/sending-msg-and-post-on-own-wall-function-no-longer-work/12257802#12257802) for more information.