# Error in Facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i m using the below fb.api code to post ito users wall.But its showing 'Error occured' alertbox. This is my code

```
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>

  FB.init({
  appId  : '3446171552628614',
    status : true, 
     cookie : true, 
     xfbml  : true, 
     channelUrl : 'http://WWW.MYDOMAIN.COM/channel.html',
      oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
    }
  );


var body1 = 'Reading JS SDK documentation1';
 FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body1 }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error)
 {
  alert('Error occured '+response.error);
 } else {
   alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
 }
});
```

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this. Thaks in advance

Comment: Do you see any additional error messages?

Comment: Did the user authorize the publish_steam permission?

Comment: What is the value of response.error?  That error string could be useful

Comment: Use console.log(response) instead of alert.. Then we will know if the issue is regarding auth or not. The API seems to be properly loaded; otherwise you would get FB not defined. Don't forget to request publish_stream permission as well.

Comment: i have gave "alert(response)". Its displaying only object

Comment: That’s why you were instructed to use _console.log_ instead of alert …

Answer (score 0):

Based on the snippet that you have posted, which seems to have nothing wrong with it, and your tag `facebook-javascript-sdk`, I believe you have encountered the `API Error Code: 191` bug.

Refer to the solution posted in [Sending msg and post on own wall function no longer work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027511/sending-msg-and-post-on-own-wall-function-no-longer-work/12257802#12257802) and see if it solves your problem.